# Storing in memory and "freezing" React components in tabbing system

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabs

I'm trying to create a tabbing system. Here is the simplified version of the code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Test({ id }) {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={text}
        onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Type something..."
      />
      <h1>{text}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(0);

  const [components, setCompoents] = useState([
    <Test key="1" id="1" />,
    <Test key="2" id="2" />,
    <Test key="3" id="3" />,
  ]);

  const handleActiiveChange = () => {
    setActive((active + 1) % components.length);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleActiiveChange}>Switch Tab</button>
      change: {active.toString()}
      <div>{components[active]}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In the final version, new tabs will be added dynamically to `components`. Although the current code sort of "works", the components (`Test`) do not preserve state as I would have hoped. The goal is that whenever a tab is rendered it keeps its previous state (e.g.: if I typed something in it, and then I cycle back to the tab I typed in it should not be lost.

What are common and best practices to "freeze", or store a react component in memory?

Ideally, the Test component (or whatever components will be put into this system) should not know anything about if they are active, or that they are in a tabbing system. They should just be regular components.

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 3):

Storing or "freezing" the state of a React component as you have described while also maintaining each component's state within the component itself, rather than lifting it up, can be achieved by rendering all components simultaneously but conditionally showing/hiding them based on the currently active tab. That can be accomplished using CSS.

I see that, [when a React component is unmounted](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unmounting), its state is lost and when it is remounted again, it starts with a fresh state. So, to preserve the state of the components, you would need to... avoid unmounting them.

A possible solution would be to render all the components, but only displaying the *active* one.
But... that means also keeping them all in memory, which can limit the scalability of this solution.

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Test({ id }) {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={text}
        onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Type something"
      />
      <h1>{text}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(0);

  const components = [<Test key="1" id="1" />, <Test key="2" id="2" />, <Test key="3" id="3" />];

  const handleActiveChange = () => {
    setActive((active + 1) % components.length);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleActiveChange}>Switch Tab</button>
      change: {active.toString()}
      <div>
        {components.map((component, index) => (
          <div style={{ display: active === index ? 'block' : 'none' }}>
            {component}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

That means all the `Test` components are rendered at the same time. Each `Test` component is wrapped in a `div` element, and the display style of this wrapper `div` is conditionally set based on the active index. Only the active component is displayed, the rest are hidden. Since all the components are rendered, their state should be preserved between tab switches.

---

> Is there a way to make it work without rendering all tabs, and somehow "freezing" the components?

"Freezing" a component's state while also unmounting the component is somewhat against the grain of how React works. React uses a virtual DOM where each component maintains its state while it is mounted. When a component is unmounted, its state is lost.

However, there is a workaround that may suit your needs, using React's [`useRef`](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_useref.asp) or [`createRef`](https://react.dev/reference/react/createRef) to store the state outside of the component, but without lifting it up to the parent component.
You can create a reference to each component's state in a `Map` that is indexed by the component's `id`.

```js
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';

function Test({ id, active, savedText, setSavedText }) {
  const [text, setText] = useState(savedText);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setText(e.target.value);
    setSavedText(id, e.target.value);
  };

  if (!active) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={text}
        onChange={handleChange}
        placeholder="Type something..."
      />
      <h1>{text}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(0);
  const savedText = useRef(new Map());

  const setSavedText = (id, text) => {
    savedText.current.set(id, text);
  };

  const handleActiveChange = () => {
    setActive((active + 1) % 3);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleActiveChange}>Switch Tab</button>
      change: {active.toString()}
      <div>
        {[...Array(3)].map((_, i) => (
          <Test
            key={i}
            id={i}
            active={active === i}
            savedText={savedText.current.get(i) || ""}
            setSavedText={setSavedText}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The `Test` component accepts a `savedText` prop that is the previously saved state for that component and a `setSavedText` function that updates the saved state. The `savedText` map is kept in a `useRef` to preserve its value across renders without causing unnecessary re-renders.

When the value in the `Test` component changes, it calls `setSavedText` with its `id` and the new `text` value. That saves the state in the `savedText` map so it can be retrieved and set as the initial state when the `Test` component is next mounted.

Comment: thank you for your time! My initial solution was very similar, but I was thinking if whether or not there is a way to make it work without rendering all tabs, and somehow "freezing" the components.

Comment: @LaczkóÖrs I agree, it would be best to *not* have to render all components. So far, I have not found a way to do that.

Comment: @LaczkóÖrs I have edited the answer to propose an alternative which would avoid rendering.

Comment: Thank you! Good idea upvoted. For now, I'm keeping the bounty on, let's see what other solutions there may be.

Answer (score 1):

After mounting the *Test* component, the default value is set in the *useState* hook. In order for it to "remember" the value after unmounting, you need to take this state higher, you can put it inside the parent component - *App*. After that, using the props, you will be able to throw the necessary data into the components you need.

For more convenient work with data, you can use various state managers - for example, [redux](https://redux.js.org/) or [mox](https://mobx.js.org/README.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, the whole point is not to lift the state up. State should remain in ``Test`.

Comment: Hm, in this case, you can use a different approach. If you want to store the state inside these components, then instead of unmounting them, you can simply hide them, in the likeness of display: none.

Comment: That would be my last resort. I want to "store" the components or "freeze" them while not being "active".  Unfortunately, it turns out it's not that simple. :)